# xDebug randomly starting a lot of connections on port 9000 (nginx)

Tags: php, nginx, xdebug

I am encountering the following issue with xdebug:

When i try to connect to xDebug and start debugging by sending a request with from the browser with `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug`, a lot of connections are being made to port 9000, as shown by `netstat -a | grep 9000`

This seems to happen randomly. If I'm lucky, netstat -a | grep 9000 will just show one connection and everything works fine. But when there is more than one connection debugging won't work. The only solution then is to stop the debugger, and kill all the connections on port 9000.

The problems started when swithcing from Apache to Nginx a while ago.

nginx version: nginx/1.6.1
running on Ubuntu Server 12.04.5 LTS with PHP 5.5.15

xdebug config:

```
xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.2.5
IDE Key => marijn

Supported protocols => Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol => $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 100000 => 100000
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => On => On
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce the problem, it consequently happens when i start my debugging session in  Chrome (with the extension 'xDebug Helper') earlier than my debugging session in netbeans.

So the problem is resolved by first starting my debugging session from netbeans, and then in chrome.